# Javascript auto-sort in firefox vs Other browsers

Tags: javascript, firefox

Recently I found this odd behavior in Firefox:

This code auto-sort the properties:

```
var an_obj = { "4": "d", "1": "a", "2": "c"};
alert(Object.keys(an_obj)); // will alert "1, 2, 4"
```

While this one is not:

```
var value2 = {"1003":1, "1001":2, "1000":3};
alert(Object.keys(value2));// will alert "1003, 1001, 1000"
```

Any number greater than 1000 will have a different behavior in Firefox while other browsers(Chrome, IE11) will behave as expected auto-sorting numbers greater than 1000.

I believe this is a bug in FireFox, am I wrong?

**Update 1**

This makes the order "unpredictable" inside the same implementation of FireFox. I could understand values not being sort at all or sort accordingly one criteria but not behaving "unpredictably" after an "arbitrary" number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug. Objects do not guarantee any order in their properties and any ordering with `Object.keys` in some cases should not be depended on.

It is stated in [§15.2.3.14 ECMAScript 5 standard](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.14) about `Object.keys` that

> If an implementation defines a specific order of enumeration for the for-in statement, that same enumeration order must be used in step 5 of this algorithm.

which implies that any ordering for the `for-in` statement and `Object.keys` is entirely implementation-dependent.

Comment: But the behavior is not consistent but instead erratic working in one way with some values in this case values greater than 1000. Why other browsers behave logically and sort and firefox is not?

Comment: @Dalorzo Because no browser is required to sort the keys. Other browsers may happen to do it, but there is no requirement in the ECMAScript specification that they do so.

Comment: but this is inside the same implementation of firefox there are 2 behaviors for the same action

Comment: Any user will call this a bug if in a web page I have grid sorting values differently if value is greater than 1000

Comment: @Dalorzo There *are no guarantees* about any ordering object keys. The fact that Firefox sometimes orders things and sometimes doesn't is just an implementation detail, not a bug. The problems in your application are the fault of depending on implementation-specific behavior, not Firefox's fault. If you need the keys to be sorted, you should sort them.

Comment: The  order "unpredictable", don't you think it makes sense to consider this a bug?

Comment: @Dalorzo No. If you need a predictable order, you should use an array. The language specification makes it clear that the order of keys in an object is not required to be predicable.

Comment: The reason the order is "unpredictable" is that there are actually different storage mechanisms for dense indices and sparse indices.  The former are stored in an array and enumerated in order; the latter are stored in a hashtable and enumerated in the order they were added.  The main reason for the difference is that it reduces memory consumption while improving performance compared to having to maintain some sort of consistent behavior for different index sizes.  And since the spec allows the behavior, there's no reason not to do it...

Answer (score 2):

The [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) does not define an ordering for the properties returned by `Object.keys`, but instead leaves that up to the implementation:

> If an implementation defines a specific order of enumeration for the
>   for-in statement, that same enumeration order must be used in step 5
>   of this algorithm.

As for the specific implementation used by Firefox, [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the properties of the object manually.

And indeed if you try it, you will see that this is indeed the case:

```
for(var o in {"1003":1, "1001":2, "1000":3}) 
    console.log(o); 
// 1003, 1001, 1000
```

No other guarantees are made about the ordering of the results. In other words, it's not a bug, it's just part of the nature of the different implementations. But you can call it a *quirk* if you like.

Comment: This would be true for all values including those below and greater than 1000. But it is not working like that, ins't it?

Comment: @Dalorzo The point is, different implementations can return them in any order they see fit. You shouldn't *expect* it to be consistent across all implementations.

Comment: but this is inside the same implementation of firefox there are 2 behaviors for the same action

Comment: @Dalorzo So? they only guarantee that it's consistent with the behavior of a `for-in` loop, and indeed it is. Therefore, it's not a bug.

Comment: The  order "unpredictable", don't you think it makes sense to consider this a bug?

Comment: @Dalorzo it's only a bug if it deviates from *specified* behavior. otherwise, it's just a design decision. In fact if you had written code which assumed a certain behavior which wasn't specified, then *that* would be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add to my own question that I was able to find that someone already submitted this behavior to Firefox Team:

The answer as correctly explained by @Peter Olson and @p.s.w.g was:

> Yeah, enumeration ordering is unspecified.  Don't rely on it!

ES7 is supposed to correct this while the final decision regarding this issue was to bite the bullet and leave it  unresolved.

For people interested on this you can find the full reference here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865760

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the unpredictable behavior by using sort. I'm assuming you already know this and are trying to get feedback on a possible bug, but in case you don't, or someone else needs to know:

```
var value2 = {"1003":1, "1001":2, "1000":3};
var sorted = Object.keys(value2);
sorted.sort();
alert(sorted);
```

Presents the values in the expected fashion in firefox.