# Sort javascript array with non-numeric keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Here is my array :

```
var a = [];
a["P.M.L."] = 44;
a["P.CO."] = 56;
a["M.É.D."] = 10;
```

Now i am trying to sort the array so it looks like :

```
["M.É.D." : 10, "P.M.L." : 44, "P.CO." : 56]
```

I have tried many solutions and none of them have been successfull. I was wondering if one of you had any idea how to sort the array.

Comment: You mean: "Here's my array, but I really want an object"? And objects have no order...

Comment: That isn't an array, it is an _object_.  JavaScript arrays have strictly numeric keys, but objects use the `[]` syntax to access properties when they are dynamically determined. Otherwise they would be dot properties.  (technically you declared it as an array, but then added additional object properties to it)

Comment: And, object properties in JavaScript are inherently not ordered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027971/javascript-auto-sort-in-firefox-vs-other-browsers

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Not exactly true. ES specifies this as not order but the only exception in Modern Broswers is Firefox

Comment: Use a collection: `[{name:'pml',val:44},{name:'pco',val:56},...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your issue here is not just the sorting but also how your data structure is set up.  I think what you will actually want here is an array of objects, that looks something like this:

```
var a = [{name: "P.M.L", val: 44},
         {name: "P.CO.", val: 56},
         {name: "M.É.D.", val: 10}];
```

With this new way of organizing your data, you can sort `a` by the `val` property with the following code:

```
a.sort(function(x, y) {
    return x.val - y.val;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution will be:

```
a.sort(function(x, y) { 
    return x.name - y.name;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken straight from the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
a.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.name > b.name)
      return 1;
    if (a.name < b.name)
      return -1;
    // a must be equal to b
    return 0;
});
```

But this really isn't an array, so you'll have to restructure that into one.

Comment: Think you can just do `return a.name > b.name`.