# Not able to place JSON values after a nested element?

Tags: javascript, json

If I were to do this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "numbers": {
     "one": "1",
     "two": "2"
  },
  "jay": "son"
}
```

This will not work. However, if I were to place the "jay" value before the "numbers" object, It will work. Is this supposed to be like so or have I just made a punctuation mistake?

Comment: According to [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/), it's valid.

Comment: What's your question?  The JSON posted here is 100% valid.  http://jsfiddle.net/gG2rt/

Comment: This is perfectly valid JSON and will work in Javascript ... where exactly do you have the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumeration ordering is unspecified in ECMAScript 5 or earlier. You should not rely on it. However browsers order the JSON Properties and except for Firefox this is an standard behavior:

Please find further discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21027971/1959948).

[Javascript auto-sort in firefox vs Other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21027971/1959948)