# Javascript multiple dimensional array sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort this array on vCount (descending) but I can't figure out how to do so. I've searched stack overflow but I can't find anything similar to my issue.

This is what I came up with this far, I guess this doesn't work because vCount is deeper in the array but how do I get deeper in the array within the sort function?

```
var nar = trck_urls.sort(function(a, b){ // trck_urls is the array
  return b['vCount'] - a['vCount'];
});
```

This is the array I'm trying to sort. (console.log output)

```
[ '/home': [ pageTitle: 't1',
    Visitors: [ 'oPc-Gr6SYxN1AMyw8Pst' ],
    vCount: 1 ],
  '/dash': [ pageTitle: 't2',
    Visitors: [ 'jepoSdBR9_ur3XSu8Psu', 'WIO4fEt1Ue8yHCly8Psv' ],
    vCount: 2 ] ]
```

Comment: array has invalid object syntax in it, can't sort an object

Comment: FYI [About objects sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21027971/1959948)

Comment: If that's the output of `console.log`, you've [abused JavaScript arrays](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/). If it's your script, then you've got a syntax error.

Comment: @Dalorzo thats not a issue because it's for Node.JS but thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @Bergi console.log output yes. Will read that article later when I have some more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you coerce your data structure into something easily sortable like this:

```
var trck_urls = [
  { path:'/home',
    pageTitle: 't1',
    Visitors: ['oPc-Gr6SYxN1AMyw8Pst'],
    vCount: 1 },
  { path:'/dash',
    pageTitle: 't2',
    Visitors: ['jepoSdBR9_ur3XSu8Psu', 'WIO4fEt1Ue8yHCly8Psv' ],
    vCount: 2 }
];

var sorted = trck_urls.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.vCount - a.vCount;
});
```

If you need to store the data as an object, you can coerce the object into an array whenever you need to sort it, like this:

```
var sortUrls = function(dict){
  return Object.keys(dict).map(function(key){
      var item = dict[key];
      item.path = key;
      return item;
  }).sort(function(a, b){
      return a.vCount - b.vCount;
  });
}

var trck_urls = {
  '/home' : { 
      pageTitle: 't1',
      Visitors: ['oPc-Gr6SYxN1AMyw8Pst'],
      vCount: 1 },
  '/dash' : {
      pageTitle: 't2',
      Visitors: ['jepoSdBR9_ur3XSu8Psu', 'WIO4fEt1Ue8yHCly8Psv' ],
      vCount: 2 }
};

var sortedUrls = sortUrls(trck_urls);
```

In this case, Object.keys() gives you the list

```
['/home', '/dash']
```

and map lets you replace each of those keys with the corresponding data, thus coercing the original object to an array. Then the array can be sorted.

Comment: Hi Eric, I like a structure like this however I need to be able to get the vCount, Visitors and pageTitle by path. Thats why I chose to use the path as key. Or is there another way to get the values by path with this structure?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you could store the data in an object, where the path is the key, and coerce that object to an array before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the `sort` function, what you are trying to sort is actually an empty array with a bunch of additional properties (`/home`, `/dash`). So if you want to sort them, you need to first create an array where the elements are the properties of your original array:

```
var array = [];
for (var key in nar) {
    array.push({key:key, value:nar[key]});
}
array.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.value.vCount - a.value.vCount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Noziar. This works partially, unfortunately it breaks the Visitor array.