# Angular $http.get always change the order in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

КI have `metadata.json` on my server.

```
{
    "type":    "list",
    "columns": 2,
    "buttons": [
        "jobs",
        "agencies",
        "career_guide",
        "livelihood_guide"
    ]
}
```

It is sort of self construction navigation. The `buttons` property is actually a folders which contain the same file with other description.

The problem is when I Ctrl+F5 or Command+R (hard refresh) in the browser, those buttons listed in correct order. But when I click button then back, I mean start navigating the order is changed until I refresh the page again.

How I can make sure the order is the same? I need the order exactly like it is entered in `json` file.

Comment: What are you using to display the buttons?

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="(i, button) in buttons">`

Comment: Use `orderBy` in your `ng-repeat`.

Comment: But it will order by value? Actually I do not need any ordering. I need to list them in order that was entered in JSON. Can you give ann example of `orderBy`?

Comment: [About properties sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027971/javascript-auto-sort-in-firefox-vs-other-browsers). Basically enumeration ordering is unspecified. You shouldn't rely on it!

Comment: @Dalorzo, That's when iterating object keys, not arrays. Sergey, The iteration order of `buttons` shouldn't just change like that. Could you setup a fiddle that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider expanding the button array of strings to an array of objects.  If each entry becomes an object with an order value and a name you can guarantee that the display order is exact.  You could either create these objects server-side when you build the JSON, or in your controller before you put the buttons into `$scope`.

[orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) sorts numerically and alphabetically out-of-the-box; neither of which satisfy your ordering requirements. Implementing an order identifier will allow you to take advantage of the `orderBy` method.  [Here's a fiddle of what I'm suggesting](http://jsfiddle.net/berrysa/HB7LU/4075/).

Comment: Can I just change JSON file to `"buttons": {"key1":"jobs","key2":"agencies","key3":"career_guide","key4":"livelihood_guide"}`?

Comment: `orderBy` only supports arrays, so if you would like to use an object instead you will have to write your own filter. [Something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18186947/1756430).